# multiple JPA repositories against same schema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an app which, depending on it's deployment config, can write the same data into one or more databases that have the same schema. Basically think of it like there's an A environment a B environment and in A we write to the A AND the B databases so that there's data from both environments there.

Further confusing the issue is that the DBs in the environments MAY (and often do) have different schemas. Though they are only different in that a change may have been made to A but not B yet.

Currently I am handling this through creating basic "entity" pojos that match the table structures and then writing specific JDBC queries for each side and then conditionally running them based on a config check.

I would love to be able to use like spring jpa to handle all the queries and allow me to do some DI for testing but the only way I can see to do this is to basically create a separate repository "AXyzRepository" and "BXyzRepository" for each Entity and perhaps even different entities for the different schemas.

Is there a way to tell a repository to like "hey, this time I want you to use /this/ ConfigurationProperty" or whatever? And to ignore any missing fields from an entity?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)** to setup different db sources, schema.sql (that initialize db) and data.sql (to load initial data).

For example, you need two profiles: 'dev' and 'prod'. In `application.properties` you set parameter `spring.profiles.active` for example to `prod` value as default (and other options common for both profiles):

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=prod
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Then you create two `application-${profile}.properties` files, for `dev` and `prod` profiles in your application `resources` folder:

**application-dev.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mydb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.platform=h2
```

**application-prod.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/mydb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.platform=mysql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Then you have to create two `schema-${platform}.sql` and two `data-${platform}.sql` files (for `h2` and `mysql` platforms):

**schema-h2.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE...
...
```

**schema-mysql.sql**

```
DROP TABLE...
...
CREATE TABLE...
...
```

**data-h2.sql**

```
INSERT INTO TABLE...
...
```

**data-mysql.sql**

```
INSERT INTO TABLE...
...
```

In your dev environment you can set command line parameter `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` (or setup it right in your IDE. For example in InelliJ IDE you can setup Spring profile in Run/Debug Configuration dialog) and work with H2 DB.
When you deploy your app to prod server it will use `prod` profile as the default.

More info is in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

Comment: If I did that then when setting the profile to "prod" it would only write to mysql://myhost:3306/mydb. I need it to concurrently write to multiple databases with the same structure